# All ordered pairs $(a, b)$ where $a$, $b$ coefficients of quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Suppose the quadratic $x^2 + ax + b$ equals $0$ when $x = c$ or $x = d$. If $c^2d + d^2c = 10$, and $a$ and $b$ are integers, what are all possible ordered pairs $(a, b)$?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: $c+d=-a$ and $cd=b$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum of roots $= - \dfrac{\text{coeff} (x)}{\text{coeff}(x^2)} = -a \Rightarrow \color{blue}{c+d = -a}$
Product of roots $=  \dfrac{\text{const. term}}{\text{coeff}(x^2)} = b \Rightarrow \color{blue}{cd = b}$

> $c^2d+d^2c = cd(c+d) = -ab$

Could you proceed further?